# Problems with Parsers

Tags: parsing, haskell

i hope somebody can help me to understand the following code

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]

item :: Parser Char
item = \ s -> case s of
    [] -> []
    (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

returnP :: Parser a
returnP a  = \s -> [(a,s)] 


(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
p>>=f = \s -> case p s of
    [(x,xs)]-> f x xs
    _ -> []


twochars :: Parser (Char,Char)
twochars= item >>= \a -> item >>= \b -> returnP (a,b)
```

Everything seems to be clear but i dont understand the lampda function in the last line in the twochars-function. It would be nice if somebody can give me a explanation about that.

Comment: Can you say at what level things are unclear? Do you understand the syntax? Is the precedence confusing? Do you understand how the variables are scoped? Are you confused about the behavior? Is `twochars` exposing the bug in your implementation of `(>>=)`? In short: what bits do you want explained?

Comment: sry i forget to tell that the Prelude (>>=) where hided. i want to have explained \a and \b and why this works. everything is clear but i cant unterstand the last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the `twochars` function for clarity and it is basically:

```
twochars = 
  item >>= \a -> -- parse a character and call it `a`
  item >>= \b -> -- parse another character and call it `b`
  returnP (a,b)  -- return the tuple of `a` and `b`
```

The lambdas here just introduce names for the parsed characters, and let them be passed along to a later part of the computation.

They correspond to the second argument in the bind you have defined:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a        -- your item
      -> (a -> Parser b) -- your lambda returning another parse result
      -> Parser b
```